# fork and pipes not working out well, they execute at the same time

Tags: c, fork, pipe

Here's the piece of code I currently have:

```
 int main () 
  {
  int pid, fd[2], i;
  char comanda[1000], *var, vect[100][100], text[100];
  if((pid = fork()) < 0 )
  {
    perror("fork error");
    exit(1);
  }
  if(pid){ 
      printf("enter command: \n");
      scanf("%[^\t\n]", comanda);
      close(fd[0]);
      close(0);
      var = strtok(comanda, " ");
      i=0;
      while(var != NULL)
      {
        strcpy(vect[i], var);
        var = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
      }
      if(strcmp(vect[0], "login") == 0)
      {
          write(fd[1], "login", 5);
          printf("I got login");
      }
      close(fd[1]);
      wait(NULL);
  }
  else
  {
      close(fd[0]); 
      int i=0;
      read(fd[0], &text, sizeof(text));
      printf("This is the child ");
      exit(0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

while the expected output would be:

1. Enter command:
2. I enter command here-
3. he writes in the pipe
4. he writes "I got login"
5. he goes in the child and processes my text

the output I get is kind of weird:

1. "Enter command:" from parent... then
2. "This is the child" from the child ?!?!?! from where?!?!
3. asks the input, the scanf
4. writes "I got login" from the parent.

This is kind of weird, all I want is to read something in the parent, write in the pipe and send it to the child process which should actually do something with that value.

Comment: I believe you forgot to create a pipe.

Comment: What do you think will happen in the child process 'read' when you have just closed the file descriptor?

Comment: my stupidity level: 99999. Let's see if it works

Comment: Corrected, still runs like that.. parent, runs the printf...then the child, runs the printf... then parent again, the scanf... I need it to run the parent first, ALL of it... write in the pipe... and then the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere do you initialize the `fd` array so that it actually contains valid file descriptors.  The child's call to `read` therefore fails immediately with an invalid file descriptor (you should be checking return codes of all system calls), which explains the "unexpected" output from the child.

In the parent (ie, before calling `fork`) you need to initialize `fd` as follows:

```
pipe(fd);
```

and delete

```
close(fd[0]);
```

from the child, since you need to read from that fd.

Comment: Corrected, still runs like that.. parent, runs the printf...then the child, runs the printf... then parent again, the scanf... I need it to run the parent first, ALL of it... write in the pipe... and then the child.

Comment: btw, now it doesn't show "I got login" anymore when I add "login" as the input

Comment: I added the pipe(fd) after the fork initially..now I added it before and it actually works, this is great, thank you so much!